# What can happen in a non-deterministic world?

Tags: science-based, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions, future

I was reading about a theoretical charged Black Hole known as the **Reissner Nördstrom Black Hole**, where should someone enter its Cauchy Horizon, will end up in a world not bound by determinism. What this means is that in this world, the past no longer affects the future, or cause does not properly affect effects *like they should*.

https://news.berkeley.edu/2018/02/20/some-black-holes-erase-your-past/

Theoretically, if this Black Hole is possible, and able to be maintained, and someone were to be thrown inside (*successfully without the gravitational spaghetti effect happening*) to this indeterministic universe, what could possibly happen there? Additionally, since such a world causes people to have their pasts erased, would it make them immortal or immune to time paradoxes?

Comment: Realistically? Everybody dies. Actually, life is flat out impossible, since any "process", by definition, involves causality.

Comment: Are you sure you mean determinism and not causality? The former is the idea that the same situation, if set up the same way twice, will evolve identically in both cases. The latter is the idea that cause precedes effect. Unless there’s some unusual meanings of determinism I haven’t encountered yet?

Comment: Determinism follows the idea that past affects future. But I guess that is a more "limited" notion of causality. I think I should edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Einstein: "is the moon there when nobody looks, classically?"

Comment: I really didn't want to VTC this question - but it's so *broad.*  What can happen without determinism? ***Anything and everything.*** Where do we start with an answer that has any hope of being selected as better than the rest? If you can think of a way to make this objective and narrowly scoped, I'll happily (even delightfully) reverse my vote.

Comment: In addition to @JoeBloggs's remark, here's a post on Cauchy horizons that might make some things clearer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13986/56299.

Comment: Literally anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part is possibly the easier one: by crossing the Cauchy-horizon we traveled far beyond the point where time as we are used to it still exists. As there is no time in a black hole we can't really talk about things like 'immortal' or 'time paradox'. Those things don't exist anymore, as your linked article already hints:

> (…) as an observer approaches the horizon, time slows down, since clocks tick slower in a strong gravitational field. As light, gravitational waves and anything else encountering the black hole fall inevitably toward the Cauchy horizon, an observer also falling inward would eventually see all this energy barreling in at the same time. In effect, all the energy the black hole sees over the lifetime of the universe hits the Cauchy horizon at the same time, (…)

The other part is a bit difficult. In a world without determinism there could happen literaly **anything**. Or Nothing, as it is also a world without time. This world would mainly depend on chance without action and result have to be linked in any way. I have to admit, I'm not able to describe a world which is absolutely random in every detail and where no physical laws (which mainly depend on determinism) exist.

Comment: Well, the only way to say it is yeah, it is not just the past that is gone: There is hardly any time there at all. In fact, such a dimension would almost be like the bulk stuff we see in Interstellar.